# I messed up my /var/www while setting up localhost server with LAMP

Tags: lamp

I have messed up my var/www folder, and need to reinstall WHOLE apache2 stuff to get it working again, and empty my folder. Tips how to do this? Im trying to setup localhost server, but I messed things up. My var/www contains folders:

example.com, test.com and html.

Comment: What do you mean you messed up the folder?  What is messed up about it?

Answer (score 0):

By default on a Linux machine with Apache2 installed, `/var/www/` contains only `html/` and `/var/www/html/` contains only index.html (which is an html page for test purposes only). If `example.com` and `test.com` do not contain your own web pages you can safely get rid of them. Put your own pages in folders under `/var/www/html/`.